# on duplicated key syntax error

Tags: c#, sql

I want to perform an insert operation into my table, but when a duplicated key is found, an update on a specific column must be done, so I used duplicated key SQL function, and the debugger shows this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'duplicated key undate timeout ='0'+'2'' at line 1

Here is my code:

```
query = "insert into regrouper values('" + nummach + "','" + numpan + "','" + date.ToString(format) + "','" + timeout + "') on duplicated key undate timeout ='"+oldtime+"'+'"+timeout+"'";

commandDatabase = new MySqlCommand(query, databaseConnection);
MySqlDataReader myReader4 = commandDatabase.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: `on duplicate key update` not `on duplicated key update`.  But also, you need to use parameterized queries instead of munging query strings.

Comment: Any time you have an SQL question you need to tell us what version of SQL (SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle? PostgreSQL?) you are using because the syntax is different.

Comment: ok, thank you for your help

Comment: The issue is with your spellings. its "duplicate key" not duplicated key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its just a spelling mistake..
Write "update" instead of undate
[See Examples](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/)

```
 query = "insert into regrouper values('" + nummach + "','" + numpan + "','" + date.ToString(format) + "','" + timeout + "') on duplicated key update timeout ='"+oldtime+"'+'"+timeout+"'";

    commandDatabase = new MySqlCommand(query, databaseConnection);
    MySqlDataReader myReader4 = commandDatabase.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: After fixing on duplicated to on duplicate and undate to update , it works thnak you

Answer (score 0):

Check your spellings. Also better use string.Format for string concatenations.

```
    query = string.Format(
        "insert into regrouper values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}') on duplicate key update timeout ='{4}'+'{3}'",
        nummach, numpan, date.ToString(format), timeout);
```